# Realm and android gradle

Tags: android, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

android builds from app centre, bt crashes on launch , I have
"realm": "5.0.0",
"react-native": "0.57.8",

gradle-wrapper.properties => distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

build gradle => classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

Comment: Couple of days back I used realm for react native and it worked well. Can you share more details about it and perhaps share some code snippets. I can share my code for reference if there is any issue regarding syntax or approach.

Comment: for me it seems more like gradle compatibility with realm, cuz realm was 2.2.0 before and it worked well with it, my Xcode was updated to 11.2 and realm broke, so I that to upgrade realm to 5 and it worked fine with Xcode. now the android broke. Not sure y, cause it builds  with no error bt wen I launch, it crashes. and FYI my node is 10.